# Sufficient information to uniquely determine a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $T=(V,E)$ be a finite tree with vertex set $V$ and set of edges $E$. Let $A\subset V$ be a subset containing all vertices of degrees $1$ and $2$. Assume that for every triple $(p,q,r)\in\binom{A}{3}$ of vertices in $A$ we know its *middle point*.

[image]
In the left picture $b$ is the middle point of $(p,q,r)$. In the right picture $q$ is the middle point of $(p,q,r)$.

Is this amount of information sufficient to uniquely determine $T$, or is there a second tree with the same vertex set, the same middle point information, but different set of edges?

Comment: does every triple have a middle point?

Comment: I'm not sure if a "middle point" is always well defined.  In your examples one might interpret the property to mean a point which would disconnect all three points if the edges of the middle point are removed.

Comment: I am sorry for the sloppy definition, so let me try to explain it once again. Given any triple of vertices, either there is a fourth vertex (distinct from the previous three) such that removing all edges incident to this vertex will disconnect the tree, and the three vertices are in distinct connected components. Otherwise, one and only one of the three given vertices has the property that removing all edges incident to this vertex disconnects the tree, and the other two vertices are contained in distinct connected components. Is the concept of a middle point clear now?